# How does consistent hashing in haproxy work?

Tags: haproxy

There was such a question. I would like to understand in theory how the consistent hash algorithm works in haproxy. To be more precise, what is hashed and how is it hashed? (what happens on the servers). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I came along [this post](https://medium.com/vimeo-engineering-blog/improving-load-balancing-with-a-new-consistent-hashing-algorithm-9f1bd75709ed) which describes it pretty nicely. Also [hash-type](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#4.2-hash-type) option documentation provides some details.